# Zip iterators of different lengths

Tags: rust

I was looking at the following code that checks if a string is a prefix of the other.

```
pub fn prefix_matches(prefix: &str, request_path: &str) -> bool {
    let mut prefixes = prefix
        .split('/')
        .map(|p| Some(p))
        .chain(std::iter::once(None));
    let mut request_paths = request_path
        .split('/')
        .map(|p| Some(p))
        .chain(std::iter::once(None));

    for (prefix, request_path) in prefixes.by_ref().zip(&mut request_paths) {
        match (prefix, request_path) {
            (Some(prefix), Some(request_path)) => {
                if (prefix != "*") && (prefix != request_path) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            (Some(_), None) => return false,
            (None, None) => break,
            (None, Some(_)) => break,
        }
    }
    true
}
```

I'd like to understand why `.chain(std::iter::once(None))` is necessary. I know it is probably for "padding", but I'm not exactly sure how it helps.

Consider the example `prefix_matches("/v1/publishers", "/v1")`. Without `.chain(std::iter::once(None))`, the next of "v1" for the second argument "/v1" is `None` as any iterator ends with `None`, so that the second iteration of the for loop should be for `(publishers, None)`, and the function "should" return false. But I got a panic by removing `.chain(std::iter::once(None))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine what the iterator returns in your example:

assume `iter = prefixes.by_ref().zip(&mut request_paths)`

###### Without inserted `None`

| # | iter.next() | prefix | request_path | request_paths.next() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `Some((Some(""), Some("")))` | `Some("")` | `Some("")` | `Some(Some(""))` |
| 2 | `Some((Some("v1"), Some("v1")))` | `Some("v1")` | `Some("v1")` | `Some(Some("v1"))` |
| 3 | `None` because `request_paths` is exhausted | - | - | `None` |

Because `request_paths` is exhausted before we see a difference the for loop exits and we return `true`

###### Now With inserted `None`

| # | iter.next() | prefix | request_path | request_paths.next() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `Some((Some(""), Some("")))` | `Some("")` | `Some("")` | `Some(Some(""))` |
| 2 | `Some((Some("v1"), Some("v1")))` | `Some("v1")` | `Some("v1")` | `Some(Some("v1"))` |
| 3 | `Some((Some("publishers"), None))` | `Some("publishers")` | `None` | `Some(None)` |
| 4 | not reached because we return early | - | - | `None` |

We see that in the second variant where we chain a `None` at the end of `request_paths` we can observe that `prefixes` has more elements and thus can early return a `false` in this case:

```rust
(Some(_), None) => return false,
```

The other `.chain(...)` isn't needed at all since all you do if the prefixes iterator returns `None` is break the loop and you could in fact shorten your function to this:

```rust
pub fn prefix_matches(prefix: &str, request_path: &str) -> bool {
    let mut prefixes = prefix.split('/');
    let mut request_paths = request_path
        .split('/')
        .map(|p| Some(p))
        .chain(std::iter::once(None));

    for (prefix, request_path) in prefixes.by_ref().zip(&mut request_paths) {
        match request_path {
            Some(request_path) => {
                if (prefix != "*") && (prefix != request_path) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            None => return false,
        }
    }
    true
}
```

Comment: Without inserted None, the program panicked instead of returning true (as stated in the question): https://rust.godbolt.org/z/xjvjcdjTs

Comment: Yes of corse because your `assert!` ensures that you return `false` but the function returns `true` instead. But that `assert!` isn't in the question.

Comment: Oh thanks, I misunderstood. In this case, why is request_path not `None`? I thought the `next` of `Some("v1")` for `request_path` is `None`.

Comment: I've added what the `request_paths` iterator would return each iteration, does that make it clearer? @tqw

Comment: When `request_path` is `Some("")`, why is `request_paths.next()` `Some(Some(""))`? I thought it should be `Some("v1")`.

Comment: And... My confusion is: we know `request_paths` is exhausted when the iterator points to `None`. But if we add another `None` to it, why is this added `None` different from the "original" `None`?

Comment: The end of the iterator is reached when `next` returns `None` but it will return `Some(None)` for the chained `None`

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use `itertools`'s [`zip_longest()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.zip_longest):

```rust
use itertools::{Itertools, EitherOrBoth};

pub fn prefix_matches(prefix: &str, request_path: &str) -> bool {
    for item in prefix.split('/').zip_longest(request_path.split('/')) {
        match item {
            EitherOrBoth::Both(prefix, request_path) => {
                if (prefix != "*") && (prefix != request_path) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            EitherOrBoth::Left(_) => return false,
            EitherOrBoth::Right(_) => break,
        }
    }
    true
}
```